# Imagemagick resize image with heigh and aspect ratio constraint

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to resize any image by determining its aspect ratio and then resizing it to a height of 800px with the width depending on its aspect ratio

```
ex1. 3200x1600 -> 1600x800 
ex2. 1000x1000 -> 800x800
```

What is the best way to achieve this using Imagemagick?

Comment: Already answered on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265436/imagemagick-convert-to-fixed-height-proportional-width and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200909/imagemagick-convert-to-fixed-width-proportional-height